# Identify this word association card game please!

Tags: identify-this-game

This is a purchased card game with special cards. It can be 2-4 players I think.

Each card has a word on it like BLUE. There is a common discard pile like in Rummy. Let’s say the top card is the word BLUE. The next player has to choose and play a card from their hand that relates to the word BLUE somehow. For instance if they had the word SAD, this relates to the word BLUE. Then the next player has to play a word relating to SAD.

What is this game called?

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of [Linkity](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15396/linkity).  It plays as you described except each card contains a single letter, not a full word.  When you play a card, you announce a word that starts with that letter.

So in your example, the starting player had a "B" card and began the round by playing it and announcing "BLUE".  Then another player responded with their "S" card, announcing "SAD".

Note that play is simultaneous: all players compete in real time to find the next association as quickly as possible.